# Performance Comparison of Some Common Sci-Fi Propulsion Systems

Tags: science-fiction, hard-science

Want to share some performance comparison I've done recently.

How does a torch ship compare in interplanetary travel to a reactionless drive? How does a reactionless drive compare to a boost drive?

Specifically, a torch ship is an ion engine scaled up to expel more reaction mass out the back (and thus produce more thrust). A torch ship expels a plasma at velocity substantially close to the speed of light. Because of this incredibly high speed exhaust, the torch ship hits the best performance limit of the rocket equation.

Despite what some pages may say, for this question, a reactionless drive is one that does not expel reaction mass out the back to produce thrust. A solar sail might qualify, but this might just be a hypothetical motor where the rocket equation no longer applies (but conservation of energy still does).

And a boost drive is the Alcubierre-White-Lentz positive energy soliton solution described in "Breaking the Warp Barrier: Hyper-Fast Solitons in Einstein-Maxwell-Plasma Theory" by Erik W Lentz.

Comment: You are asking for a hard science comparison of things that don't exist. It is like asking which is faster, a pegasus or a unicorn.

Comment: I'm asking for citations and equations. I may be mistaken, but I don't think the "hard science" tag restricts us to stock cars and things you can pull off the shelf.

Comment: The hard science tag becomes problematic when conservation of momentum is waved away.

Comment: There are several concepts here, if you'd really like to dive deep into reactionless - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactionless_drive

Comment: Here's one that hasn't been ruled out, and contains the basic equations you would need : force and energy - https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20190029294/downloads/20190029294.pdf

Comment: @JamesMcLellan, it's been ruled out: the author failed to consider momentum transfer during the "beam acceleration" phase, only calculating the momentum transfer at the ends of the particle accelerator.  Once you factor that in, you get zero net acceleration.

Comment: @Mark , thanks for the update! Do you have a hyperlink, so that I can read the details?

Comment: No luck on that.  I saw it mentioned in passing in a discussion of perpetual-motion machines and other physical impossibilities.

Answer (score 2):

### Performance Comparison for Intrasystem Travel

For a 10,000 kg vessel in a boost field 100 meters in radius and 1 meter thick, attempting a trip from Earth to Mars (13 light minutes) at 1 gee (9.8 m/s/s) acceleration -

For a rocket, ion drive, or torch ship using antimatter fuel -

- $ v_{max} = \sqrt{2 s_{half} a } = \sqrt{2 \cdot ({{13}\over{2}}\cdot 60)  c \cdot a } = \sqrt{76,440 c} = 0.5 \% c$
- $ m_f = m_i (1 - { {1 } \over { e^{ \delta{ \% } } } } ) = (10,000) (1 - 0.9975) = 24.96 $ kg

For a reactionless drive using antimatter fuel -

- $ v_{max} = \sqrt{2 s_{half} a } = \sqrt{2 \cdot ({{13}\over{2}}\cdot 60)  c \cdot a } = \sqrt{76,440 c} = 0.5 \% c$
- $ m_{fuel} = { { {1\over2} m v^2 } \over c^2 } = { { {1\over2} (10,000) (76,440 c)} \over c^2 } $ = 1.274 kg

For a boost ship, with a reactionless pilot engine -

- $ v_{max} = \sqrt{2 s_{half} a } = \sqrt{2 \cdot ({{13}\over{2}}\cdot 60)  c \cdot (100 \cdot a) } = 5\% c $ [1]
- $ E_{tot} \approx C v_s^2 { {R^2} \over {w} } $ = [2] 25 kg
- Which does not include the pilot drive fuel $ m_{fuel} = $ 1.274 kg = 25 + 1.274 = 26.274 kg

Where -

- $ C  $ is a form factor, approximately 1.0 in most cases
- $ v_s $ is the speed of the spacecraft as viewed by an outside observer (the "boosted" speed)
- $ R $ is the internal radius of the boost field, in meters, and
- $ w $ is the thickness of the boost field, in meters

### References

[1] https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110015936/downloads/20110015936.pdf

[2] "Breaking the Warp Barrier". Erik W. Lentz

### Commentary

In the regime of sub-light travel between planets, the boost drive is extremely reasonable. If the energy costs provided in the article are correct.

The boost drive energy cost depends only on size of the field : not mass of the ship, nor time the field is up. It assumes, I think, that there is no force countering the boost field that must be overcome by adding more power. This independence from mass and time can be exploited, I think, over longer hauls; but I haven't thought about it yet.